# Is there a way to represent/call Java's or operator in Mathematica?

Tags: java

In Java, I can do

Int char = '～' | 0x10000

Is there a way to call this Java code in Mathematica?

I checked https://reference.wolfram.com/language/JLink/tutorial/CallingJavaFromTheWolframLanguage.html and could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: I don't know Java, but are you looking for `BitOr`?

Comment: do you actually want to call Java here, or are you looking for a Mathematica equivalent? If you want an equivalent, then if you could describe what you want to do in non-java language, that'd be great!

Comment: There's probably a better way: `BitOr[First@ToCharacterCode["~"], 16^^10000]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need this as you could just do this directly in *Mathematica*:

```
BitOr[First@ToCharacterCode@"~", 16^^10000]
```

But if you want to do it with *JLink* then follow these instructions:

Quit Mathematica. This is important because *JLink* likes to hold on to old definitions even somehow evading `` Clear["Global`*"] `` / `` Remove["Global`*"] ``

Create a class and compile it:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static long myfunction()
    {
        return '~' | 0x10000;
    }

    public static long bitwiseOr(long a, long b)
    {
        return a | b;
    }
}
```

Copy the built file *MyClass.class* somewhere, for example C:\ or your documents folder.
Make sure this folder is in your CLASSPATH. You may need to add this to your environment variables.

Then open Mathematica and run:

```
Needs["JLink`"]
LoadJavaClass["MyClass"];
MyClass`myfunction[]
```

You should get result 65662. Note I made *myfunction* a static method, so you use a backtick ` to access it. If it were not static you'd use `JavaNew` and `@` to create an object and call a method on it, but that's all in the docs.

I also added `bitwiseOr`, you can use it like `` MyClass`bitwiseOr[3,5] ``